# Object initializer with conditional statement

Tags: c#, object, initializer

How can I simplify conditional statement inside object initializer so that code will be more readible? If addNew is true, then new item is added to dictionary, otherwise it will have only one item.

```
...
var channel = new ChannelConf {
Name = "Abc"
Headers = !addNew ?  new Dictionary<string, string> 
          { 
               [Constants.Key1] = Id
          }
          : new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
               [Constants.Key1] = Id,
               [Constants.Key2] = Port
          }
}
...
```

Comment: Might want to identify the language with a tag.

Comment: you might think of using constructor overloading `new ChannelConf(bool addNew)`

Comment: How about *not* using conditionals in initalizers? `if (addNew) { channel.Headers.Add(Constants.Key2, Port); }` after the initialization is a vast improvement. Remember, initializers are only shorthand for after-the-fact property assignments anyway. You do not get a prize for squeezing everything in one block.

Answer (score 1):

You could call a method to initialize `Headers`:

```
...
new ChannelConf {
Name = "Abc"
Headers = GetNewDictionary(addNew)
}
...

private Dictionary<string, string> GetNewDictionary(bool addNew)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> output = new Dictionary<string, string> { [Constants.Key1] = Id };

    if (addNew) { output.Add(Constants.Key2, Port); }

    return output;
}
```

Alternately, you could leave it the way that it is and reduce the number of lines:

```
...
var channel = new ChannelConf {
Name = "Abc"
Headers = !addNew ?  new Dictionary<string, string>  { [Constants.Key1] = Id }
          : new Dictionary<string, string> { [Constants.Key1] = Id, [Constants.Key2] = Port }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good practice to let things done through a parameterized constructor. It might be a common api consumed by others, so it is going to be easy for you to document and not have to tell how consumer should use the api.

```
public ChannelConf(bool addNew)
{
    Headers = !addNew
        ? new Dictionary<string, string>
        { [Constants.Key1] = Id }
        : new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            [Constants.Key1] = Id,
            [Constants.Key2] = Port
        };
}
```